# VNC server listens on three ports (5800, 5900 and 6000) what does port 6000 do?

Tags: linux, vnc

I have a CentOS server with vncserver service configured. netstat tells me that Xvnc listens on 5800, 5900 and 6000 ports.

What does port 6000 do for Xvnc?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That port seems to be used by the X11 graphics system

> `# grep 6000 /etc/services`
>
> `x11             6000/tcp        X               # the X Window System`

Maybe xvnc is using some kind of port forwarding for X11

Answer (score 1):

- 5800 is apparently a web server that provides a basic VNC client.
- 5900 is the actual VNC client.
- 6000 is the X server itself. It isn't forwarding anything. `vncserver` *is* an X server. Client apps (i.e. GUI apps that you run) connect to it via this port to display windows.